# silverlight animated UI

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to put some tabs in the first page, and when mouse is over it, it should be bold and get larger, when click, it will direct to different page.  Is it going to involve with JavaScript ? any tutorial for this ?

Answer (score 0):

For the URL, you will want to read about [The Silverlight Navigation Framework](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx).

To make the URL go bold and get larger, you will want to use setup a MouseOverState VisualState Storyboard, as is done here: [Style the MouseOver on a Silverlight/WPF button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401519/style-the-mouseover-on-a-silverlight-wpf-button).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. But all of them is about color changes

Comment: I'm assuming you're resilient enough to substitute `Foreground = Black` with `FontWeight = Bold`. You've got to show a little effort on StackOverflow.com ;)